# Tracking Position with RaspberryPi for LiDAR-Mapping

Tags: python, mapping, raspberry-pi4, texture-mapping, lidar

I'm currently working on a project to map my surroundings via lidar. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but the sensor will be moving during the measurement (e.g. mounted on a rover/drone).
As you can probably guess, I need a way of knowing the sensor's current position to properly convert and store the measurement inside a mesh / coordinate system, because my Intention is to create a big map created by all measurements.

My first attempt was via a 6-axis accelerometer, but the accuracy of calculated positions is low to begin with and on top of that fades over time.
Then i thought of using a GPS module, but the accuracy would be too little here too (a few meters, when centimeters are needed).
Of course one could deduce the current position by tire revolutions, but this doesn't consider tires slipping, and when  it comes to drones, this approach goes down the river...

I thank you guys in advance for your help!

#################################

My environment:

- Raspberrypi 4b 8gb
- TF-Luna sensor
- preferably Python, but hey, I'm open to other languages if they prove useful (could use sockets to transfer data)